# Latex with matplotlib, axis label not correct

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, data-visualization

I'm trying to use matplotlib for creating plots and use them inside my latex document.
Actually it works quite good to use latex-style fonts inside the plots, but for some reason the first label of each axis has another layout then the other labels, it seems to be thicker.
This is may code

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,8))
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
suptitle = plt.suptitle("Test plot", y=1.02, size=13)
ax.plot(dummydata1)
ax.plot(dummydata2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("test.pdf", bbox_extra_artist(suptitle,), bbox_inches="tight")
```

When I open the saved image it looks like this. (zoomed in)
You can see that the `0.0`and the `0.05`are different.

[image]

Does anybody knows what could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set rcParameters which apply to the axes ***before*** creating the axes. I.e. instead of

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,8))
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
```

use

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,8))
```

Explanation: If you you create the axes, one "master" ticklabel is created. This will have the normal default font settings applied to it. Then the default font settings are changed. In consequence they apply to all ticklabels that are created after changing the setting. Those are all but the master ticklabel.